# Plot special character as ① in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, character

I search the Internet, find nothing about typing special character like ① in matplotlib.
Is there code to represent the ‘①’ to display in the figure?

For now, I use:

```
## the ① character was found on the Internet, and I clipped it.
ax.text(0.425, 0.475, u'①', ha='center')
```

I think there must be some function to generate ①, ②, ③, ④ ...as a type of special character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circled numbers start at Unicode code point 0x2460 and go up to 20. So just write a little helper function that returns the desired character:

```
def circled(x):
    return chr(0x245F+x)    # Python 2: use unichr() instead of chr()
```

Usage:

```
ax.text(0.425, 0.475, circled(1), ha='center')
```